# Scaffold with white theme applies over main layout in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, scaffold, compose-recomposition

Why I have invisible Scaffold over layouts?

I have scaffold with floatingActionButton, snackbarHost and bottomBar.
In the main layouts I have some fields with Column and element are AndroidView:

```
AndroidView(
        factory = {
            RichEditor(it).apply {}
})
```

But on the recomposition sometimes applies some scaffold layout (screen) which fill all the fields, only  bottomBar can be seen on screen. But if I click on this blank place all elements will be seen without recomposition.

[image]